# "'Timestamp' object does not support indexing", 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to work on a dataframe where I have to make a new column which will fill the result given by the xnpv function

```
def xnpv(rate, values, dates):

    if rate <= -1.0:
        return float('inf')
    d0 = dates[0]    # or min(dates)
    return sum([ vi / (1.0 + rate)**((di - d0).days / 365.0) for vi, di in zip(values, dates)])

F['newcolumn'] = F.apply(lambda x: xnpv(0.1, x['Cash'], x['Date']), axis=1)
```

when I execute the above code it gves me the following error: TypeError: ("'Timestamp' object does not support indexing", 'occurred at index 0')
Please help me solve this issue

When i use the following expression

```
F['newcolumn'] = F.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: xnpv(0.1, x['Cash'], x['Date']))
```

it gives me another error : KeyError: 0

[image: example]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example for the `F` dataframe?

Comment: In the F dataframe I only require two columns which are "Cash" which have values in float and Date column which have date in datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is happening at step

```
d0 = dates[0]
```

`dates` will be a timeseries. I think you were assuming it would be the full "dates" column. When you itterate over a pandas series, with `apply(lambda x: f(x) axis=1)` x is a row, not a column. therefore `x["date"]` will be a timestamp, not a series as you were expecting.

Edit: maybe a vecotrised rather than one relying on `.apply()` would be better?

```
def xnpv(rate, values, dates):
    return  values / (1.0 + rate) ** ((dates - dates.min()).dt.days / 365.0)
F['newcolumn'] = xnpv(0.1, F['Cash'], F['Date'])
```

Edit 2: This seems to work for me. Is it consistent with what you were expecting?

```
F = pd.DataFrame({"name":['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
              "cash":[1,1,3,4,1,2,4,5],
              "date":['2017-01-01','2017-02-01','2017-03-01','2017-04-01',
                     '2017-01-01','2017-02-01','2017-03-01','2017-04-01']
             })
F["date"] = pd.to_datetime(F["date"])

def xnpv(rate, values, dates):
    return  sum(values / (1.0 + rate) ** ((dates - dates.min()).dt.days / 365.0))
F.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: xnpv(0.1, x['cash'], x['date']))
```

Comment: I typically try to avoid using `.apply()` if I can. If you can do things in a vectorised manner it would be better (/faster). `(d['Date']-d['Date'].min()).dt.days` will give you the days for example.

Comment: I am not able to figure it out that way. Can you please help me achieve this "F['newcolumn'] = F.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: xnpv(0.1, x['Cash'], x['Date']))"?

Comment: Would this work? If you give example of F, it would be easier. Also, sorry about formatting. 
`def xnpv(rate, values, dates):`
`return  values / (1.0 + rate) ** ((dates - dates.min()).dt.days / 365.0)`
`F['newcolumn'] = xnpv(0.1, F['Cash'], F['Date'])`

Comment: I have added an image of the example above as "example"

Comment: Please see edit 2. That works for me, is it what you were expecting?